# Build x64 Libraries for OpenCV 3.1 on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: opencv, build, visual-studio-2015, 64-bit, opencv3.1

I've downloaded OpenCV 3.1 from the OpenCV website and am attempting to build static x64 libraries. I am following the procedure outlined here,

http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d52/tutorial_windows_install.html#gsc.tab=0

and am using CMake 3.5 to generate the SLN/Project files for VStudio. I didn't have any trouble compiling 32-bit static libraries, which is the default solution configuration generated by CMake. However when I try changing the build target in the configuration manager to "x64" I get multiple linkage errors and pretty much nothing compiles.

Am I missing some configuration option in CMake to generate the correct project files? If anybody has had any experience with the process I'd appreciate any help!

Cheers

Comment: Check out Lucian's VBlog https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lucian/2015/12/03/opencv-first-version-up-on-nuget/

Comment: Try also mine blog.. Works well http://funvision.blogspot.cz/2015/11/install-opencv-visual-studio-2015.html